# Changing display of Categories in Site Directory

Tags: 2007, site-directory, categories

I'd like to make some changes to the category display in Site Directory. Specifically, I'd like the results to be on the same page underneath the category list.

I looked at the possibility of changing the links on each category so that instead of going to a new page they point back to the site directory Categories page. (If the Category Results web part was added to that page maybe it would work.) However I can't work out how to change the URL from `categoryresults.aspx` to `category.aspx`.

Does anyone have experience with this sort of customisation and thoughts on how to achieve this? Custom JavaScript is to be avoided if at all possible.

Here is a mockup screenshot of what I'd like to do:

[alt text http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1185/mockuph.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1185/mockuph.png)

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a solution that does not involve javascript/ajax.  In most of the systems I've worked with there are 100s of sites so even if you wrote a component or found a way to work with the data in custom web parts the page load time would probably be horrendous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can find so far is using JavaScript (jQuery specifically). The category results web part does work when added to the same page in tests I've done so far, but something like jQuery is required to clean up its UI which isn't designed for this scenario.